# Is it possible to Rotate the label on an outer group on the X-Axis of an SSRS 2008 Chart

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a chart with multiple groups (2 to be precise) represented on the X-Axis. The first group is Quarter (three months) and the second is Person (Name) and I want to Rotate the Outer (Person Name) from horizantal to vertical -90 degree. However, I can only do so on the first group (Months-Jan, Feb, Mar).

Please let me know if it is possible to do so for the outer group.

Thanks
Tommy

Answer (score 0):

Amend category group label to:

```
="Name: "& (Fields!person_name.Value) & " Qtr: " & (Fields!quarter.Value)
```

Amend group on and sort by to the same expression.

[image: design view of category group properties]